# jQuery Mobile changepage, displaying images

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am writing a jQuery Mobile single page application.
In one of my divs (data-role="page") I have a few images (img elements) which I load in "pagebeforeshow":

```
$('#a1').attr("src", "images/smile.png");
```

When I first navigate to this page (using changepage), the image is displayed correctly, but if i click back and press the link to this page again, the image is not displayed.

If I use window.location (instead of changepage), everything work fine, but then I cannot control the transition (slide, flip etc').

Any ideas why is this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: you might want to prepare a small http://jsfiddle.net example ...

Answer (score 0):

Try using pagebeforechange instead of pagebeforeshow

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.